# CMake xib to nib compilation for iOS target

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, xib, nib

I'm targeting iOS (device and simulator) and setting up CMake to add the different resources needed in the bundle. The "xib" file is giving me some problems. If I take no further action, the iPhone/iPad simulator run fails with the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
  reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
   'NSBundle </Users/danieldekkers/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/1C29638B-7593-4311-8F94-C8051AF90AD7/Discs.app> 
      (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''
```

A missing NIB file in the bundle. 
An example (http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:OSX_InterfaceBuilderFiles) shows that for OSX, you have to compile the xib files into nib files and add these to the bundle as a post-build step.
So my guess would be that something similar holds for iOS as well.
But my question is,... where do i add the compiled nib files?

I now do this in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
# We need to compile the interface builder *.xib files to *.nib files to add to the bundle
# Make sure we can find the 'ibtool' program. If we can NOT find it we skip generation of this project
FIND_PROGRAM( IBTOOL ibtool HINTS "/usr/bin" "${OSX_DEVELOPER_ROOT}/usr/bin" )
if ( ${IBTOOL} STREQUAL "IBTOOL-NOTFOUND" )
    MESSAGE( SEND_ERROR "ibtool can not be found" )
ENDIF()

# Compile the .xib files using the 'ibtool' program with the destination being the app package
FOREACH( xib ${RSRC_IOS_XIB_FILES} )
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND( TARGET ${RT_APP_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${IBTOOL} --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text 
        --compile 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/${RT_APP_NAME}.app/Contents/Resources/${xib}.nib
        ${RT_APP_ROOT}/rsrc/apple/ios/${xib}.xib
        COMMENT "Compiling ${RT_APP_ROOT}/rsrc/apple/ios/${xib}.xib")
ENDFOREACH()
```

But iI don't really trust the "destination" of the compilation step, especially for the simulator.

Has anyone got this working or see what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this question if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 4):

It should "just work" with the CMake Xcode generator to add the *.xib files as sources to **add_executable**, and then set the **RESOURCE** target property to the list of *.xib files.

As shown in the [CMake/Tests/iOSNavApp/CMakeLists.txt](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/d2c2319d/Tests/iOSNavApp/CMakeLists.txt#L16) file.

This technique should work with CMake 2.8.5 and up, and Xcode 4 and up.

**EDIT**

Code from link copied/pasted here in case the link gets broken in the future:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5)
project(NavApp3)

set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT iphoneos4.3)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "armv6;armv7;i386")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS "-iphoneos;-iphonesimulator")

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Classes
  )

add_library(Functions STATIC TotalFunction.c TotalFunction.h)

set(M_SRCS main.m Classes/NavApp3AppDelegate.m Classes/RootViewController.m)
set(HEADERS Classes/NavApp3AppDelegate.h Classes/RootViewController.h)
set(RESOURCES MainWindow.xib RootViewController.xib)

add_executable(NavApp3 MACOSX_BUNDLE ${M_SRCS} ${HEADERS} ${RESOURCES})

target_link_libraries(NavApp3
  Functions
  "-framework CoreGraphics"
  "-framework Foundation"
  "-framework UIKit"
  )

set_target_properties(NavApp3 PROPERTIES
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER "com.yourcompany.NavApp3"
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist.in
  RESOURCE "${RESOURCES}"
  XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
  XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dsym"
  XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER YES
  XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PREFIX_HEADER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/NavApp3_Prefix.pch
  XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS YES
  XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.0
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The piece of information regarding the `RESOURCE` attribute that should be set to list the .xib files is was very hard to find on the web for me ! And the [documentation is a bit misleading](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/RESOURCE.html?highlight=resources), you would think it is a property reserved to frameworks.
By the way, there is a slight typo in the property identifier (it is singular), but I could not edit that.

Comment: Please, add the cmakelists.txt example to the answer, this link will be broken soon or late.